# Ajax javascript radio button trouble

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement, radio-button

Can anyone suggest why this isn't loading the autocomplete data? If i hardcode the URL in the ajax call, it works, but not with my code to alter the url source?
I'm unsure why it wouldn't work. If you want to look at the page as a whole, the hardcoded version is:[here](http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/orderform.html)

```
        var starterSearchData;
    $(function() {
    var destination;
        elementVal = $("input[name=radio]");    //note returns array of radio button elements
        if (elementVal[0].checked){
         destination= "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/spanish.php",
        }   
        if (elementVal[0].checked){
         destination= "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/italian.php",
        }



    //Starter Autocomplete  (Spanish)         
    var starterSearchData;
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: destination,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                starterSearchData = $.map(data, function(item) {
                    if (item.course == "starter")
                        return item.name;
                        return item.price;

                });
                EnableAutoComplete();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });

        function EnableAutoComplete() {
            $("#starter").autocomplete({
                source: starterSearchData,
                minLength: 2,
                delay: 010
            });
        }
    });
```

Radio button:

```
                <div id="radio">
                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"><label for="radio1">Spanish</label>
                <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"><label for="radio3">Italian</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: You check same element to assign url value, this is why you either get the second url if the first radio was selected, or none at all if the second radio selected -  `if (elementVal[0].checked) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors at some places in your code. This will work:

```
var starterSearchData;
$(function() {
  var destination,
      elementVal = $("input[name=radio]");

  if (elementVal[0].checked) {
    destination = "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/spanish.php";
  }   
  if (elementVal[1].checked){
    destination= "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/italian.php";
  }

  $.ajax({
      url: destination,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
          starterSearchData = $.map(data, function(item) {
              if (item.course == "starter")
                  return item.name;
                  return item.price;

          });
          EnableAutoComplete();
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
          alert(err.Message);
      }
  });

  function EnableAutoComplete() {
    $("#starter").autocomplete({
        source: starterSearchData,
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 010
    });
  }
});
```